# Deep copy of a table record - duplicate a record and all related data

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is an effective way to "deep copy" a single record in a table. By "deep-copy" I mean creating a new record that is a copy of the original (except with a new primary key), and then also creating a new, duplicate record for every data point in every other table that had a relation to the original record (except these would now reference this new copy).

For example, if there were a table of companies, departments, and employees such that for each company, there were multiple departments, and employees might work in one or more departments - how might I go about creating a new company that is an exact replica of another company, including the same departments and the same employees (except with different primary keys)?

Comment: Are there foreign keys used? If so, you may have to do a little more work since you are not copying the same primary key(s).

Comment: foreign keys would be used such that, for example, if we duplicate a company, we would create new, duplicate departments which would all reference this new company - and so on for employees.

Comment: Is this meant to be a one-time exercise or do you want this to happen after every insert/update?

Comment: it is sufficient for this to be a one time execution, or something that can be scripted and executed on an as-needed basis.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your tables I can only make some assumptions. I would approach it this way (see below). Note the inline comments.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_copy_company(source_company_id INT)
RETURNS INT AS $$

    DECLARE new_company_id INT;

BEGIN

    -- Copy the company data
    INSERT INTO companies (name)
    SELECT name FROM companies WHERE id = source_company_id
    RETURNING id INTO new_company_id;

    -- Copy the departments and return the newly created record(s) as a CTE
    WITH new_departments AS
    (
        INSERT INTO departments (company_id, name)
        SELECT new_company_id, name FROM departments WHERE company_id = source_company_id
        RETURNING *
    )

    -- Copy all employees belonging to the department(s) with new department ids
    INSERT INTO employees (department_id, name)
    SELECT
        ndpt.department_id,
        emp.name
    FROM
        new_departments ndpt
    INNER JOIN
        departments sdpt
        ON  (ndpt.company_id = sdpt.company_id)
        AND (ndpt.name = sdpt.name)
    INNER JOIN
        employees emp
        ON  (sdpt.department_id = emp.department_id);

    -- Returns the new company id
    RETURN new_company_id;

END; $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL VOLATILE;
```

Note: This assumes you have an id field for each table that has a sequence.